# How to dynamically change Datatables multiple column headers using ajax and jquery without refreshing the webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am trying to change the column number and header according to the return value of ajax, while the table data is updated using DataTables jquery plugin. Javascript and jQuery Code below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'readtitle.php', //this php contains the column header
            success:function(re){
            setTitle(re); // this function is used to set column header
            }

    });


   var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
     "bPaginate": false,
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bLengthChange": true,
     "bFilter": true,
  "bRetrieve": true,
     "bInfo": false,
     "bAutoWidth": false,
     "bServerSide": true,
     "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
     "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
     "sAjaxSource": './aadata.txt',
     "aoColumnDefs": [
        {"aTargets":[]}
     ]

   }); 
 }

function setTitle(re){
  re = re.substring(0,re.length-1);
  var retitle = re.split(",");  // this retitle can be of length 3 to 6, depends on the data

        $(retitle).each(function(index, element){
           $('#titleh').html(element);
        });
}
```

Below is my HTML-table:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr id="titler"><th>Date</th><th>Actual</th>
   <th id="titleh"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Because in the HTML, I set 3  header. If the return header is of length 3, it works fine. However, if the length changes, the function (possibly wrong):

```
 $(retitle).each(function(index, element){
           $('#titleh').html(element);
        });
```

only returns the last element, which makes the table column number fixed to 3. I don't know how to increase the column header using a loop in jQuery.

I haven been stuck for two days. Can anyone please help me?

Many thanks!!!

Katie

Comment: Hi if you run the setTitle('with what ever choice of header') in console window in the browser , is it giving desired ouput ? for me its giving

Comment: @CodingAnt Hi, thanks for replying. Indeed, it gives me the desired output. But since in the HTML table, the <th></th> number is fixed. I can't use html() function to simply add one header to it.

Comment: HI did it worked or what ?? Curious

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... please see my own answers below. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the question by changing the way of initialising table in HTML instead of altering the settings in Datatables.

What I did is: first, remove the existing table, as well as the table wrapper!

```
 $('#table_id').remove();
 $('#table_id_wrapper').remove();
```

Then initialise a new table. and set the format of header/body according to your data:

```
 var content = "<table id='table_id' class='display datatable' style='width:100%;'><thead>";
 content +='<tr>';


 re = re.substring(0,re.length-1);
 // alert(re);
 var retitle = re.split(",");
    alert (retitle + 'x');
   var c = retitle.length;
   var atarget = [];
   var stitle = [];
   for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
     atarget[i] = i;
     stitle[i] = retitle[i];
     content += '<td>' +retitle[i]  + '</td>';

   }

  content +=' </tr></thead>';
  content +='<tbody></tbody>'
  content += "</table>";
```

Then, append your table to your webpage. Here I attached it to my tab:

```
  $('#tab3').append(content);
```

Finally, I initialised the Datatable settings by changing the aoColumnDef according to my own data. Noted that the data format must match the way you previously define your HTML table

```
   var settings = {

     "bPaginate": false,
     "bProcessing": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth":false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    //  "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
     "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
     "sAjaxSource": './aadata.txt',
   "aoColumnDefs": [       
     { "aTargets":atarget}
     ]
   };

 $('#table_id').dataTable().fnDestroy();
 $('#table_id').dataTable(settings);
 $('#table_id').dataTable().fnReloadAjax();
```

By the way, thank you @CodingAnt, @JerryDDG all the same for your help.

A related question about changing the Datatable title is solved here:

[What is the right format to change Datatables column using array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730642/what-is-the-right-format-to-change-datatables-column-using-array)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should destroy the old table and create a new one with the new config.

```
$(tableSelector)
    .dataTable(dataTable_setting)
    .fnAddData(data);

$.ajax({
    url: ...
    data: ...
    success: function(data) {
        if (columns number changed) {
            $(tableSelector).empty();
            $(tableSelector)
                .dataTable(newDataTable_setting)
                .fnAddData(newData);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about this , actually your requirement is still not clear to me .

In case its right , you need to little bit fine tune according to your requirement. Its adding header if needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setTitle(re){

    re = re.substring(0,re.length-1);

    var retitle = re.split(",");  

    //destroy element created  on request
    $('th').each(function(index, element)
    {

          if(index > 2)
          {
            $( this ).remove();
          }

    });


    //For extra header if any

    if(retitle.length > 1)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= retitle.length; i++) 
        {
            $('#titler').append('<th></th>');
        };

    }

    var counter     =   0;

    $('th').each(function(index, element)
    {

          if(index > 1)
          {
            $( this ).text(retitle[counter]);
            counter ++;
          }

    });

}


</script>
```