# What is the right format to change Datatables column using array?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to change the column numbers of my Datatables after I initial the table:

where retitle is an array (i.e. an array of length 4) and c is the length of retitle (i.e. c=4), which is previously defined.

```
   var atarget = [];
   var stitle = [];
   for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
     atarget[i] = i;
     stitle[i] = retitle[i];
   }

var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
 "bPaginate": false,
 "bProcessing": true,
 "bLengthChange": true,
 "bFilter": true,
  "bRetrieve": true,
 "bInfo": false,
 "bAutoWidth": false,
 "bServerSide": true,
 "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
 "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
 "sAjaxSource": './aadata.txt',
 "aoColumnDefs": [
    {"sTitle":stitle,"aTargets":aTarget}
  ]

 });
```

But it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question by changing the way of initialising table in HTML instead of altering the settings in Datatables.

What I did is: first, remove the existing table, as well as the table wrapper!

```
 $('#table_id').remove();
 $('#table_id_wrapper').remove();
```

Then initialise a new table. and set the format of header/body according to your data:

```
 var content = "<table id='table_id' class='display datatable' style='width:100%;'><thead>";
 content +='<tr>';


 re = re.substring(0,re.length-1);
 // alert(re);
 var retitle = re.split(",");
    alert (retitle + 'x');
   var c = retitle.length;
   var atarget = [];
   var stitle = [];
   for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
     atarget[i] = i;
     stitle[i] = retitle[i];
     content += '<td>' +retitle[i]  + '</td>';

   }

  content +=' </tr></thead>';
  content +='<tbody></tbody>'
  content += "</table>";
```

Finally, append your table to your webpage. Here I attached it to my tab:

```
  $('#tab3').append(content);
```

By the way, thank you, @Volkan Ulukut all the same for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the settings like this:

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.something').click( function () {
        oTable._iDisplayLength = 50;
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I want to change the 'aTargets', what should I write? According to this link:https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11451/changing-aocolumndefs-parameters-of-a-present-table/p1, the aoColumnDefs cannot be changed, is it?

Comment: well then this is what you could do; destroy the table with bDestroy and recreate the table with your new initialisation options.

Comment: It can work, but I still have the problem when formatting the "aoColumnDefs". I edited the question and changed the code above. Could you have a look please?

Comment: c and rtitle are not defined.

Comment: They are previously defined. The result shows that if retitle is an three element array = [a,b,c],and c=3. Then the header shows **a,b,c | a,b,c | a,b,c|** instead of **a|b|c**