# Dynamic column header in datatable from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I want to populate a Datatable with a dynamic column header and column data. I can populate dynamic column data successfully, but I can't achieve a dynamic column. I am using an array I get from a JSON AJAX request. My code is this:

```
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1"></table>
</body>
```

```js
var JSONResult = '{"column1":"data1","column2":"data2","column3":"data3","columnN":"dataN"}';
var row_dtable = new Array();
var dtable_api = $('#example').dataTable();

$.each(JSONResult , function(key, value) {
    row_dtable.push(value);
}); 
dtable_api.api().row.add(row_dtable).draw(false);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `attributes`?

Comment: Sorry,I have edited code..

Answer (score 0):

`Datatables` doesn't have the ability to change it's structure once being created. You have to `destroy` it and then re-create with a new set of columns.

Additional reading: [How to dynamically change Datatables multiple column headers using ajax and jquery without refreshing the webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704428/how-to-dynamically-change-datatables-multiple-column-headers-using-ajax-and-jque)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your `JSONResult` will always have the same columns and only data will be updated. For this the solution will be to create the `columns` once in the header of your table and then using the datatable API to add the data.

First you should **change your table HTML like this**, which shouldn't be a problem.

```
<body>
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr></tr>
   </thead>
 </table>
</body>
```

Then you **create the headers through jQuery**

```
   var JSONResult = [{ "column1": "data1", "column2": "data2", "column3": "data3", "columnN": "dataN" },
            { "column1": "data1", "column2": "data2", "column3": "data3", "columnN": "dataN" }];

        $.each(JSONResult[0], function (key, value) {
            $('#example thead tr:first-child').append($('<th>', {
                text: key
            }));
        });
```

And last, **add the data to dataTable**

```
        var row_dtable = new Array();
        var dtable_api = $('#example').dataTable();
        $.each(JSONResult, function (i, l) {
            $.each(l, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key + " " + value);
                row_dtable.push(value);

            });
            dtable_api.api().row.add(row_dtable).draw(false);
        });
```